# WSO2 EMM - Install application by role

Tags: android, wso2-iot

I am trying to install an application on two android devices (different users and roles) with the "admin" account. But when I launch the installation by role, all the devices receive the installation request even if they are not in the choosen role.
And the installation is run as many times as the number of enrolled devices.
What i want is to install the application on the devices whose user belongs to the selected role.

I can't found why it is acting like that (bug, configuration,...).
Have you encountered this problem ? and is there a solution ?

I am using WSO2 EMM 2.0.1.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in EMM 2.2.0. Its Advisable to use EMM 2.2.0 and continue further.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to upgrade from EMM version 2.0.1 to version 2.2.0 ? Or do we have to re-install everything (devices, apps in store,...) ?

Comment: Currently we don't have any migration scripts for this , so you need to reinstall the system. But in the near future we are planing to provide migration scripts.